# Swift - nested navigation controller missing "edit" button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I have a library app that as you click each library it pulls up a list of shelves, which, once clicked, then pulls up a list of books on each shelf. I am having issues putting an "+" in the navigation bar on only the view showing the list of books to be able to add a book. I have tried adding it programmatically as well as with the storyboard but, although the application builds and runs properly, the button just never shows up. Any advice with this would be awesome!

below is my bookTableViewController Code:

```
import UIKit

class bookTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var addBookButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var currentShelf = Shelf()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "Shelf"

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Add"

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return currentShelf.allBooksOnShelf.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel.text = currentShelf.allBooksOnShelf[indexPath.row].bookName

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if currentShelf.allBooksOnShelf[indexPath.row].hasBeenRead == false{
        currentShelf.allBooksOnShelf[indexPath.row].hasBeenRead = true
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Read Book", message: "Thanks For Reading!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else{
        currentShelf.allBooksOnShelf[indexPath.row].hasBeenRead = false
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Read Book", message: "You Just UnRead A Book...", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        // Delete the row from the data source
        currentShelf.allBooksOnShelf.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a        new row to the table view
    }
    }


 }
```

Here is the code i use to push to this TableVC from the Shelf Table View Controller:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let vc = bookTableViewController()

    vc.currentShelf = currentLibrary.allShelves[indexPath.row]

    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you need to create a `rightBarButtonItem`, not just set the title.  Try this:

```
var barButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: @"addTapped:")
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```